# A question regarding $ZFC^{-}$

Tags: set-theory

Given $ZFC^{-}$, that is, ZFC-Powerset+Collection+Separation, is there a set of alternative axioms $X$ (other than the trivial one, namely, {Powerset}) that, when added to $ZFC^{-}$, allow one to derive Powerset as a theorem of $ZFC^{-}$+$X$ and recover full $ZFC$? (Thanks to Prof. Hamkins for setting me straight on the correct formulation of $ZFC^{-}$.)

Comment: Replacement is a consequence of ZFC-.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: ZFC- is ZFC-Powerset, correct?  If so then this is different than $ZFC^{-}$.

Comment: I was using your definition.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais:  Very well, then.  So the question now becomes, what axioms $X$ (other than the trivial axiom Powerset) when added to $ZFC^{-}$, will derive Powerset as a theorem, and recover full ZFC?  Thanks for the info, by the way.  It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Since powerset is a reasonably simple sentence, I can't really see what you're asking for.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais:  Simply put, I am looking for some set of sentences in the language of set theory that will derive Powerset.  Perhaps such a set does not exist, but it does not hurt to look. Perhaps some references of work done in this area will be a good start for me.

Comment: There are a great deal of such sets, so you probably need to be more specific.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais:  Can you prove that Replacement is a consequence of $ZFC^{-}$?

Comment: Replacement is basically a special case of collection. Depending on how it is formulated, collection might give you a set that is larger than the range of your function, but you can always trim it down using comprehension.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais:  Since there a great deal of such sets of axioms, the simplest and most 'economical' (i.e. the set with the fewest number of axioms) will do just fine, thank you.

Comment: In that case, the powerset axiom is really hard to beat!

Answer (score 2):

By compactness, if a sentence $\sigma$ is equivalent to the powerset axiom over $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$, then this equivalence is provable in [Kripke-Platek set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory) ($\mathrm{KP}$) with infinity, $\Sigma_n$-separation and $\Sigma_n$-collection for some $n$. Due to the connection between $\mathrm{KP}$ and [admissible ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_ordinal), a good place to look for this is in the $\alpha$-recursion theory literature. The only thing that came to mind were results by Evangelos Kranakis on partition relations in $\alpha$-recursion theory. I don't recall the specifics of Kranakis's work offhand, but that thought did lead me to an example.

Consider the following abstract extenson of Ramsey's Theorem to infinite cardinals.

> For every cardinal $\kappa$ there is a cardinal $\lambda$ such that $\lambda\to(3)^2_\kappa$.

In $\mathrm{ZFC}$, one can show that $\lambda = (2^\kappa)^+$ works. In $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$, one can show that if $\lambda \leq 2^\kappa$ then $\lambda\not\to(3)^2_\kappa$. Thus, if there is a $\lambda$ such that $\lambda\to(3)^2_\kappa$ then $\lambda$ must be so large that $2^\kappa \lt \lambda$.

Comment: @FrancoisGDorais:  Regarding the abstract extension of Ramsey's Theorem and its relation to $ZFC^{-}$--very interesting.  Thanks.  Since I only require that $ZFC^{-}$+$\sigma$$\vdash$Powerset and not full equivalence, is it correct to infer that by compactness, this implication is provable in $KP$ with infinity, $\Sigma_{n}$-separation and $\Sigma_{n}$-collection for some n?  What I am really after is what $\sigma$ might be.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: Ah, you don't require $\sigma$ to be a theorem of $\mathrm{ZFC}$? Yes, compactness still applies: if $\mathrm{ZFC}^- \vdash \sigma\to\mathrm{Powerset}$ then this is provable in $\Sigma_n\mbox{-}\mathrm{KP}$ for some $n$.